# "U'l'Kaparat Pesha" said during a leap year

Tags: rosh-chodesh-new-month, musaf, leap-years

During yesterday's *Ben Hashmashot* shiur, our Rav read a section from Otzar Hadinim (Eisenstein) (B"N, I'll insert the excerpt later, when I have access, or perhaps someone can edit it in.) that explained why "וּלְכַפָּרַת פֶּשַׁע" is said during a leap year. He says that it is to atone for the possibility that we made have made a mistake in making this year a leap year and that would mean that we may have been eating *chametz* during Pesach.

I have two difficulties with this reasoning, that I hope someone can answer:

1) If this is true, why are we beginning to worry about this during Tishrei and asking for forgiveness before we even did anything wrong - if, we even did anything wrong in the first place? Shouldn't we be asking for forgiveness in Sivan **after** Pesach?

2) G-d gave us the commandment to decide how the calendar works which includes how to place leap years. As it is, with the fixed calendar, the placement of the leap years are correct, with the exception of the 8th year in the 19 year cycle - currently. (This is based on the current dates and is due to the "seasonal drift" problem - discussed in a few M.Y. questions.) So, why is this statement said at all? Why should we ask for any type of "forgiveness" for adding a leap year if G-d allowed us to do so, and it turns out that a year, such as this year, **needs** to be a leap year.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/69021/chaparat-pesha-just-through-adar-ii

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3153/saying-ulichaporas-pasha-in-musaf-of-rosh-chodesh

Comment: Hi Gershon - both links are either explanations of the general timing of the phrase or explain the phrasing / reason exactly as I explained, here. It still puzzles me as to why we use this phrase at all.

Comment: Dan. I did not recommend closing your question. Links were put for those that are interested as it may help them understand better your issue.

Comment: One more question on the topic of this phrase: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35153/. Like the ones posted by Gershon, this is not a dupe.

Comment: BTW: While Nusach Sefard is וּלְכַפָּרַת פֶּשַׁע, Ashkenaz is וּלְכַפָּרַת פָּשַׁע (for anybody tempted to edit the post, I replaced the English as the OP had transliterated it.)